# How to assign value from list?

Tags: python

i have  tuples in a list :

```
a = [((1, 6), (8, 2)), ((8, 2), (6, 3)), ((6, 3), (9, 4)), ((9, 4), (5, 7))]
```

i want to assign all value in list, example:

```
A = [1,6], B = [8,2]

A = [8,2], B = [6,3]
```

then perform calculations between the elements together and print the results on the screen

```
C1 = (A[1]+B[1],A[2]+B[2])

C2 = (A[1]+B[1],A[2]+B[2])
```

Thank you!!!

```
X = [1,8,6,9,5]

Y = [6,2,3,4,7]

res = list(zip(X,Y))

a = list(zip(res, res[1:]))

print(a)
```

I can't think how to assign A and B in list

Comment: `for (A, B) in a:` and then you do what you want with them...

Comment: if tuples has 100 value, i can't do that by hand, we must use "for"

Comment: Can you details ???

Comment: What exactly do you expect to be the result of what you are doing? And why do you have such strange data as input. The B in each tuple is the same as A in the next, so you have redundancy which helps nothing. The correct input data without redundancy would be `[(1, 6), (8, 2), (6, 3), (9, 4), (5, 7)]`.

Answer (score 1):

This list comprehension should perform the operations you described

```
>>> [tuple(sum(i) for i in zip(x, y)) for x, y in a]
[(9, 8), (14, 5), (15, 7), (14, 11)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [((1, 6), (8, 2)), ((8, 2), (6, 3)), ((6, 3), (9, 4)), ((9, 4), (5, 7))]
>>> A = a[0][0] # First item's ((1,6), (8,2)) first item (1,6)
>>> B = a[0][1] # First item's ((1,6), (8,2)) second item (8,2)
>>> A
(1, 6)
>>> B
(8, 2)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

using `lambda`

```
a = [((1, 6), (8, 2)), ((8, 2), (6, 3)), ((6, 3), (9, 4)), ((9, 4), (5, 7))]
sol = list(map(lambda x:(x[0][0]+x[1][0],x[0][1]+x[1][1]), a))
print(sol)
```

output

```
[(9, 8), (14, 5), (15, 7), (14, 11)]
```